# Counting rows between dates using row number?

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the number of rows that 2 dates fall between. Basically I have an auth dated 1/1/2018 - 4/1/2018 and I need the count of pay periods those dates fall within.

Here is the data I am looking at:

```
create table #dates
(
    pp_start_date date,
    pp_end_date date
)

insert into #dates (pp_start_date,pp_end_date)
values ('2017-12-28', '2018-01-10'),
       ('2018-01-11', '2018-01-24'),
       ('2018-01-25', '2018-02-07'),
       ('2018-02-08', '2018-02-21'),
       ('2018-02-22', '2018-03-07'),
       ('2018-03-08', '2018-03-21'),
       ('2018-03-22', '2018-04-04'),
       ('2018-04-05', '2018-04-18');
```

When I run this query,

```
SELECT 
    ad.pp_start_date, ad.pp_end_date, orderby
FROM
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pp_start_date) AS orderby, * 
     FROM
         #dates) ad
WHERE
    '2018-01-01' <= ad.pp_end_date
```

I somehow want to only get 7 rows. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT - Ok so using a count(*) worked to get the number of rows but now I am trying to get the number of rows for 2 dynamic dates form another temp table but I don't see a way to relate the data.
 Using the #dates temp table referenced above gives me the date data.  Now using this data:

```
create table #stuff
([month] date,
[name] varchar(20),
units int,
fips_code int,
auth_datefrom date,
auth_dateto date)


  insert into #stuff (month,name,units,fips_code,auth_datefrom,auth_dateto)
values ('2018-01-01','SMITH','50','760', '2018-01-01', '2018-04-01');

  insert into #stuff (month,name,units,fips_code,auth_datefrom,auth_dateto)
values ('2018-01-01','JONES','46','193', '2018-01-01', '2018-04-01');

  insert into #stuff (month,name,units,fips_code,auth_datefrom,auth_dateto)
  values ('2018-01-01','DAVID','84','109', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01');
```

I want to somehow create a statement that does a count of rows from the #dates table where the auth dates are referenced in the #stuff table I just can't figure out how to relate them or join them.

pp_start_date <= auth_dateto and pp_end_date >= auth_datefrom

Here is my output for #dates
pp_start_date   pp_end_date
2017-12-28  2018-01-10
2018-01-11  2018-01-24
2018-01-25  2018-02-07
2018-02-08  2018-02-21
2018-02-22  2018-03-07
2018-03-08  2018-03-21
2018-03-22  2018-04-04
2018-04-05  2018-04-18

Here is my output for #stuff
month   name    units   fips_code   auth_datefrom   auth_dateto
2018-01-01  SMITH   50  760 2018-01-01  2018-04-01
2018-01-01  JONES   46  193 2018-01-01  2018-04-01
2018-01-01  DAVID   84  109 2018-02-01  2018-04-01

I am trying to use the auth_datefrom and auth_dateto from #stuff to find out how many rows that is from #dates.

Comment: what is your expected result from the sample data you have given?

Comment: The record at the very bottom is not between the dates you are stating in your question?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please add the corresponding tag. `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, ....

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
SELECT ad.pp_start_date, ad.pp_end_date, orderby
from (select 
row_number()over ( order by pp_start_date) as orderby, * from
   #dates) ad
  where    ad.pp_end_date <= '2018-01-01'
  or ad.pp_start_date >=  '2018-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
select d.*
from #dates d
where d.startdate <= '2018-04-01' and
      d.enddate >= '2018-01-01';
```

This returns all rows that have a date with the time period you specify.

I'm not sure what the `row_number()` does.  If you want the count, then:

```
select count(*)
from #dates d
where d.startdate <= '2018-04-01' and
      d.enddate >= '2018-01-01';
```

Comment: The count is what I was looking for!   Thank you so much!  Obviously I was overthinking it!